# Facebook app invite for android doesn't detect install

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, applinks

I've integrated the Facebook SDK for android for an app. When a user receives the app invite there's a big "Install Now" button that will link them to the google play store. The problem is even if the user already has the app installed if they open up the Facebook invite the button still says "Install Now" instead of "Open" or "Play". The iOS version does this. The reason why this is necessary is because otherwise the app has no way of receiving the custom app link sent in the invite. Am I missing something? Or this a bug in Facebook?

I've redacted a bunch of stuff, but this is the button that I think should be changing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the app link even works if the user goes to the app through the Google Play store, awesome!